# C#, access (get or read) the textBox values in a static method?

Tags: c#, methods, textbox, static-methods

I have a form (form1) that has a text field (textBox1)
I have a class that has the method "public static string getValue()"

how I can read the value of the textBox1 within the method getValue() ??

here is my code

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
      ---------------------------------
      ---------------------------------
      ---------------------------------
    }
}
```

the other class

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    class values
    {

        public static string getValues()
        {

            string v;
            v = ------get value from textBox1 in Form1
            return v;
        }

    }
}
```

the whol software is build in this structure, so I hope there is some standard way in C# to get these values in the method getValue()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate new object of Form1 and get the value. Or else add a delegate in form1 and call it from getValue, such that the return value of delegate should be the textbox value.

Comment: any example? it will help me learn and understand it better! and is this structure what I have is wrong?

Comment: Well if you instantiate Form1 in getValue method, then a new Form objects is created and new TextBox obj is created in memeory. So this wont solve the whole problem for you. 

So other way is to define delegate in form1, which obvisously is static object in form1. Then in that delegate, when called from getValues to get TextBox value, make it to return a value from form1. 

Look for delegate, youll get the answer.

Comment: Thanks allot, I will try that, I never done this before I guess :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can not. The property is in the instance of the class, the static method has no pointer to it. Broken by design.

Comment: then how it should be designed?

Comment: Unless he instantiates, shows, and disposes of the form inside the static method.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate, show, and dispose of the form inside the static method. An example:

```
public static string GetValues()
{
    string value = null;

    using (var form = new Form1())
    {
        DialogResult result = form.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            value = form.textBox1.Text;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

The using block takes care of freeing the resources allocated for the form. ShowDialog shows the form as a modal dialog.

While this works for simple dialog boxes, it is probably not what you want to do in every case. The method will block the current thread until the user closes the form. Look at other applications and sample code. As @Dan Abramov wrote, *Reconsider your design.*

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Control c in Form1.Controls) {
     if(c.getType() == TextBox) {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)c; 
            string value = tb.Text;
     }

}
```

But why don't you just read the value from the form?

```
Textbox1.Text
```

Consider the KISS-principle!

Comment: But mind it, he cant do this from getvalues method. Its in seperate/different class. And textbox obj in other class.

Answer (score 0):

With few assumptions - you can use this code snippet

```
private static void GetValue(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
{

  Application.OpenForms["FormSomeForm"].Controls["textBoxSomeTextbox"].Text = @"Some Value";

}
```

Depend on your other code it is also helpful to define the control / variable "public" as for example:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxSomeTextbox;
```

... or use the VS Studio GUI - Properties:

[image]

Tested; VS 2019 - NET 4.8 - 1/29/2022